# ISession/UnitofWork in Service Layer within Windsor tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I'm trying to build a real-world app using [this tutorial](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-ASP-NET-MVC-3-application-To-be-Seen.ashx) as a basis for the framework. I understand MVC, but am new to the whole IOC/NHibernate world. After reading a few Q&A here on SO, I am thinking of adding a Service layer between the controller and the repository as I'll be adding some business rule validations down the line.

The source on github also has a 'ServiceInstaller' that proved really useful as it allows me to add any services to the application i.e.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().Pick()
                            .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<SectionService>())
                            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Transient)
                            .WithService.DefaultInterface());
    }
```

My question is specific to this tutorial, and its basically that I'm not sure if the ISession (which is the UoW) is passed from the Service layer to the Repository, or if there's another approach.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Controller

    public class SectionsController : Controller
    {
        public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
        private readonly ISectionService sectionService;

        public SectionsController(ISectionService sectionService)
        {
            this.sectionService = sectionService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(sectionService.FindAll());
        }

    // other action methods
    }

// Service Layer

    public class SectionService : ISectionService
    {
        private ISectionRepository repository;

        public SectionService(ISession session)
        {
            this.repository = new SectionRepository(session);
        }

        public IQueryable<Section> FindAll()
        {
            return repository.FindAll();
        }

    // other methods
    }

// Repository
    public class SectionRepository : ISectionRepository
    {
        private readonly ISession session;

        public SectionRepository(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
        }

        public IQueryable<Section> FindAll()
        {
        return session.QueryOver<Section>().List().AsQueryable();
        }

    // other CRUD methods

    }
```

Is this correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason why the sample app is implemented that way. Well, actually two reasons.

First reason that it is relatively simple and there's not enough logic to warrant a separate layer yet.

Second is, that this kind of controller --> service --> repository --> ISession abstractions are pointless and add nothing to the table. Only thing they do is increase the complexity of the app and amount of work you do for no benefit.

Ayende has a nice, recent, series of blogposts about it which I highly recommend. ([here's the first of them](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/16/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the.aspx), followed by few others).

What sorts of real-world requirements do you have that would warrant those two additional layers?

In closing, YAGNI and KISS.

Comment: answer is "None that I can think of". I read Ayende's posts (incl. [this one](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx)), and don't disagree. However, being new to NHibernate/IOC, one tends to look for "best practices", and the overwhelming majority of posts and code samples out there utilize the repository/service layers. 

Followup question: I know you're super-busy, but any chances you'll be adding additional parts to your excellent (and simple) tutorial in the near future (and maybe do away with the sample EventsRepository)?

Comment: @seekay, I've no plans to work on it in the most immediate future. However we're open for ideas. Also @Hadi Eskandari (@heskandari on twitter) is another person working on the tutorial, so if you have some good ideas, he might have some time to put them into action.